# How to receive cursor and show details in delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures

I am working in an application where i have created procedure with 4 In parameters and returns a cursor, now i want to call this procedure in delphi and use this cursor to show the data, but im getting an error in that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_ACTIVITY
(
   P_FROM_DATE      IN      varchar2,
   P_TO_DATE        IN      varchar2,
   P_SITE           IN      NUMBER,
   P_CATEGORY       IN      NUMBER,
   CURSOR1_         OUT     SYS_REFCURSOR
)
```

and Im using TStorProc in delphi for the same

```
 sp_Activity.prepare;
 sp_Activity.ParamByName('P_FROM_DATE').AsString := cseS_DateRapportCalendar.Text;
 sp_Activity.ParamByName('P_TO_DATE').AsString   := lgiDBDateTimePicker1.Text;
 sp_Activity.ParamByName('P_SITE').AsString      := cseL_Installation.Text;
 sp_Activity.ParamByName('P_CATEGORY').AsString  := cseL_CategorieProgramme.Text;
 sp_Activity.ExecProc;
```

How can i fetch that cursor and use it here in delphi
This is the error that Im getting .

[image]

Comment: I've set in in the object inspector

Comment: @nolaspeaker `VARCHAR2` is an Oracle type.

Comment: Whenever you use the SQL tag, it's also necessary to add a tag for the specific DBMS you're uisng, as syntax and functionality differs between them. It's relevant enough that the tag description you see when hovering over the tag tells you to do so. Please [edit] to add that tag. Thanks.

Comment: If you mean TStoredProc, that's a BDE component.  The BDE has been obsolete for well over a decade, so use something (read: anything) else.  Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Btw, what error are you getting, exactly and on what line of your code?  You can see your screen, we readers can't.  You need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your q as well as the DBMS tag requested by @KenWhite.

Comment: The [`TStoredProc.ExecProc()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.TStoredProc.ExecProc) documentation says: "*If a stored procedure returns output parameters, they are stored in the `Params` property when `ExecProc` returns control to the application. An application can access the output parameters by indexing into the `Params` list, or by using the `ParamByName` method.*" For example: `sp_Activity.ExecProc; CursorParam := sp_Activity.ParamByName('CURSOR1_'); // use CursorParam as needed...` But I have no idea how to access a `SYS_REFCURSOR` from an output `TParam`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau , what would be CursorParam Type ?

Comment: @ArpitMishra `TParam`, like I said. However, your error message says you are trying to execute `GET_ACTIVITY_INFO`, but your SQL says the name is `GET_ACTIVITY`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau i fixed that, its working now. Thank you